# Loop to format numbers using number format plugin

Tags: jquery, for-loop, number-formatting

I am wondering what I am doing wrong with this plug in, or if my syntax is incorrect.  I have an array with 7 numbers that each number in that array i'm trying to format so I can use them in a legend.  If I type it all out by hand and format each number it works but is a whole lot of code to type and maintain.  "state" is the array I want to format and store the formatted numbers in "strRound".

Thanks in advance to those that help out.

Here is my code:

```
var strRound = $.formatNumber(state, { format: '#,###', locale: "us" });        

    for (var i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
        state[i] = $.formatNumber(state, { format: '#,###', locale: "us" });
    }



    globals.map.on("load", function () {
        if (population || totalHousingUnits) {
            $("#row1").html(strRound[0] + " - " + strRound[1]);
            $("#row2").html(strRound + " - " + strRound);//same formatting for legend
            $("#row3").html(strRound + " - " + strRound);
            $("#row4").html(strRound + " - " + strRound);
            $("#row5").html(strRound + " - " + strRound);
            $("#row6").html(strRound + " - and Greater");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be, as you are formatting state[i], not state the array?

```
 state[i] = $.formatNumber(state[i], { format: '#,###', locale: "us" });
```